# Is the overhead for utilizing a vector with insert() as a priority queue relative to utilizing a heap? (c++)

Tags: c++, performance, vector, heap, overhead

I am currently working on a project where I implemented a vector of structure pointers to use as a priority queue. I use a for loop to determine position in the vector (if not less than the back) and then use `insert()` to place the struct pointer in position in queue. I am using `back()` as the front of queue so I can maintain the pop functionality of the vector.

I was just trying to determine if using the heap library instead would add a speed increase, as this project is dependent on time. Can provide code if you'd like, size of the heap/vector may increase tremendously as this is a tower of hanoi A* search algorithm.

Figured I would ask for future knowledge as well to save me some debug breakpoint shuffles if anyone knew offhand.

Comment: Why not simply use [`std::priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)? What parts of your requirements lead you to implement it yourself?

Comment: Hard to say for sure. `vector`'s contiguous data makes insert operations surprisingly fast.

Comment: so does `std:priority_queue<T, std::vector<T>>`

Answer (score 2):

I've made a simple benchmark of first inserting `N` random `int`s into a priority queue and then popping `N` top elements.

Expectedly, sorted `std::vector` with linear search wins when the queue size is small, and `std::priority_queue`, which is implemented as a max-heap with `O(log N)` worst-case insertion time, wins when the queue size is large.

[image: Priority queues benchmark - Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770]

Benchmark code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/eugnsp/1d0ad3581f9429bd4aff6e64b4c7b408).